# "have you ever been required to leave any country other than the UK"

Tags: visas, uk, applications

That's a question on the standard UK visitor visa application. I've visited quite a few countries other than the UK, and (like any other visitor) was required to leave before my visas expired which is what I've always done. Does that mean I need to answer yes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, of course not. The question refers to whether you have been deported, removed etc. See Part 6 of https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf