# My Schengen visa got revoked mid-trip, what should I do?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, overstaying, visa-shopping

Originally, I was planning to do a trip to Switzerland (entry) and then travel to Slovenia. Slovenia was going to be my main destination so I got the visa from them. But just a day before the trip, I decided that it’s not worth the trip to go to Slovenia since it was a long train ride from Zurich.

I did disclose this during the entry in Zurich to the immigration officer and he seemed fine with the change and had no issue getting the entry stamp. I thought this would suffice. Little did I know. Slovenia embassy apparently learnt about this change and sent me an email saying they have revoked my visa mid-trip and I’m expected to leave the Schengen zone immediately.

My trip is of 10 days and I’m now into my 6th day when I received this letter. It’s not going to be easy to change my return flight now. What should I do? What happens if I continue my trip and leave 4 days after revokation? What is the penalty of my whole dibacle? Admittedly I didn’t take this change of plans too seriously. I’m hoping I don’t have to pay the price too much

Comment: Are you *cough* really sure you got that email?  Emails go missing all the time.

Comment: That’s one way to put it ;) I still wonder what’s the penalty in future, if I apply for Schengen again

Comment: Visa is used to grant entry, visa on its own means nothing for your stay. If the visa is revoked you cannot enter, it doesn't mean you have to leave

Comment: @littleadv That's true for the US (where _visa_ doesn't necessarily equate to _status_, but it may not be true everywhere.

Comment: You can contact the authority which revoke your visa for explanations (and be ready to go there: it was you main reason for the travel). Apologies and tell them about misunderstand (which you had). Or check plan-B: go in Balkans (on non-Schengen countries), or Turkey, or UK (which would be easier to you go enter). Is the train travel so long (compared to the flight you had to go to Zurich?). A stop in Venezia or in Austria would be worthwhile. And if ZRH reported you, maybe there were other suspicion facts.

Comment: I tried that, but had no luck. Slovenian embassy was pretty adamant. My original hotel in Slovenia reported them when I cancelled my booking. 

Anyway, I exited Switzerland without any issue. They didn't even mention anything on the exit. I'm not sure what the repurcurssions would be now, if I apply for Schengen again. Does anyone know?

Comment: If a visa is revoked and you don’t leave by the date given you would be overstaying. The repercussions of this revocation and order to leave include that you’ll have to declare it in any future visa application that asks about such things, and getting another Schengen visa is likely to be much harder

Comment: @Traveller It would only have an effect of subsequent Schengen visa applications if border guards decide to impose a ban when they notice the overstay (which does not seem particularly likely for a few days). Other than that, the date of exit and overstay wouldn't be recorded anywhere. I assume border guards might however stamp the revoked visa's sticker to mark it as invalid. Both this and the record of the revocation could make future visa applications more difficult.

Comment: What made you change your mind? You presumably knew how long the train ride from Zurich to Slovenia was when you applied for the visa?

Comment: Slovenia is bordered by Italy, Austria, Hungary, and Croatia. A tourist trip combining Switzerland and Slovenia isn’t therefore the most obvious itinerary, did you have a specific reason for choosing it? Your tale sounds like a case of visa shopping to me, TBH

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica indeed, it is certainly not true in the Schengen area; the visa must be valid for the duration of the traveler's stay.

Answer (score 9):

> I tried that, but had no luck. Slovenian embassy was pretty adamant. My original hotel in Slovenia reported them when I cancelled my booking. Anyway, I exited Switzerland without any issue. They didn't even mention anything on the exit. I'm not sure what the repercussions would be now, if I apply for Schengen again. Does anyone know?

There is a record of your revoked visa shared between Schengen countries that may prompt further scrutiny when you apply for your next visa. At the same time, if the visa has really been “revoked” and not “annulled”, it's not so bad as only the latter suggests deception and the former is more of a technical measure (I don't think it was really intended to be used in the way it was here).

Answer (score 4):

The reason you have to apply for a visa with the country that is the main destination of your trip is to spread the workload, and to counter visa shopping. Since you violated the rules your visa got revoked. Because currently there is not a lot of data being exchanged between countries on visa issues you got away with it, but you may not get way with this in the future, when the entry/exit system becomes operational.

And what will you answer when you apply for a visa and one of the questions is "have you ever been refused a visa, or had one revoked"?

Comment: While entries and exits are not yet recorded or shared, visa information (applications, refusals, revocations…) IS recorded and shared. Any new application for a Schengen visa in the next 5 years should immediately bring up this incident, whatever the country OP applies for a visa from.

Comment: What rule did the OP violate? They did apply to the country they intended to be their main destination. Also, in practice, the entry-exit system wouldn't change much here (or in general). Entry through another country than your main destination are expected (and was always the OP's plan) and travel within the area is not going to be tracked by the proposed system. On the other hand, as @jcaron pointed out, visa revocations are recorded in the VIS.

Comment: Another question: Which country asks if you ever had a visa revoked?

Comment: How does this answer the question " what should I do?" It's really just rubbing salt in the wound, which doesn't appear to help in any way.

Comment: @Relaxed IIRC, the UK asks whether visitor visa applicants have ‘ever been required to leave’, which covers revocation.

Comment: @Traveller Your comment helped me find https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131356/have-you-ever-been-required-to-leave-any-country-other-than-the-uk You actually provided a lot of info on that there, thanks!